# get validTo date from x509 certificate using openssl-php

Tags: php, openssl, pyopenssl

Need to get validTo (expiry) date from x509 certificate and validate with current date. Am using openssl_x509_parse($crtdata) to parse the certificate, any thought on how to get the validTo date from the resulting array. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the resulting array

Answer (score 1):

Why do not you use print_r which will print the array and gives out the indices or key you need?

I think you can try the following

```
 $arr = openssl_x509_parse($crtdata);
 /*To get the validTo*/
 $validTo = $arr['ValidTo_time_t'];
```

This is given as an example at PHP manual page of [openssl_x509_parse](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-x509-parse.php).

I hope this would help you. But you may face issue in future. Consider this program to update if you plan to update PHP version and test it well.

Comment: Why would they "face issue in future"?

Comment: Because documentation says " The structure of the returned data is (deliberately) not yet documented, as it is still subject to change.".